# Scanner Methods

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a program that will use Scanner to view an imported file and add the "comparables" insides into a Binary Search Tree. However, I do not know what type of value will be passed in the file (Integer, String, etc.). Therefore, I cannot use the methods: `.next()` or `.nextInt()` when traversing the file. Is there a method that will alow me to pass any object inside the file?

Comment: Why exactly you can't use `next()`?

Comment: should be fine to read it with `next` or `nextLine` even if the file contains integers because everything will be represented as a string. just convert it to integer when you want or any other type.

Comment: Let's see some example file data.